# Access to primefaces widgetvars on document ready

Tags: jquery, primefaces

Im trying to access to primefaces components on document ready like this:

```
$(function() {
  var showDialog = getUrlParameter("showDialog");
  if (showDialog == "true") {
    PF('myDialog').show();
  }
});
```

But in that moment the primefaces widgetvars are not available and I get the following error:

> Widget for var 'myDialog' not available!

In PrimeFaces 6.2 and 7.0 (and maybe some earlier versions) the error you get is

> TypeError: PF(...) is undefined

but when `PrimeFaces.widgets['myDialog'].show()` is used instead of `PF('myDialog').show();` the error is comparable

> TypeError: PrimeFaces.widgets.myDialog is undefined

When are the primefaces widgetvars ready to be accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better solution for my case. I call a JavaScript method using the `onload` attribute of `h:body`

```
<h:body onload="checkIfShowDialog()">
```

And this is the JavaScript method:

```
function checkIfShowDialog(){
  var showDialog = getUrlParameter("showDialog");
  if (showDialog == "true") {
    PF('myDialog').show();
  }
}
```

This works as desired.

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but can you add the PrimeFaces version you were using to the question and answer? This does not seem to be valid anymore for recent PrimeFaces versions...

Comment: Or maybe your page was relatively slow to load so the dialog widget was already initialized when the `onload` runs

Comment: I had success with this, so it could well be situation-specific. Still worth trying.

Answer (score 9):

I had success with adding the javascript initialization code in the page AFTER the component with the widgetVar, ie

```
<p:dataTable widgetVar="test">

</p:dataTable>

<script  type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()  {
     PF('test'); // access and do whatever here
 }
</script>
```

Putting the script tag before the p:dataTable doesn't work.

More info here: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=35718

Comment: You are missing ); after the }
Complete JavaScript would be: 
  $(document).ready(function()  {
     PF('test'); // access and do whatever here
 });

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the widgetVar needs some time to get initialized (in document.ready), like (non-extensive)

- upload
- dialog
- overlay

in that case you can use setTimeOut

```
setTimeout(PF('myDialog').show(), 2000);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you mean `setTimeout(function() { PF('myDialog').show();},2000)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this error when usin a `p:remoteCommand` with `autoRun="true"`,  like this

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:remoteCommand autoRun="true" name="actualizarSaldosCajero"
            onstart="PF('ajaxStatus').show();"
            action="#{plantillaGeneralMB.actualizarSaldosCajero}" />
    </h:form>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="ajaxStatus">
       Content
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

You should place the `p:remoteCommand` code **after** the components that you reference in the `onstart` or in a function you call from there.

```
<h:body>
    <p:dialog widgetVar="ajaxStatus">
       Content
    </p:dialog>

    <h:form>
        <p:remoteCommand autoRun="true" name="actualizarSaldosCajero"
            onstart="PF('ajaxStatus').show();"
            action="#{plantillaGeneralMB.actualizarSaldosCajero}" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

(Tried with PrimeFaces 6.2 and 7.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call javascript initialization method from server side using RequestContext.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("initialization script here");
```

For example:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if(!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("alert('This onload script is added from backing bean.')");
    }
}
```

Reference: [Execute javascript onload](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3002)